# Can I use an existing report adapter class in SSRS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

Referring to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599551/can-i-use-an-existing-dataset-in-ssrs), at least can we reuse the report adapter class which we've used for Crystal Reports.

We're migrating to SSRS from Crystal Reports. Currently for Crystal Reports, we've DataAccess classes which have methods to call stored procedures. These DataAccess methods are being called inside the corresponding ReportAdapter class methods to fill the dataset table columns.

Can we use this route in SSRS? We're trying to reuse these classes and methods in SSRS instead of directly binding the data using stored procedures.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is not common as the most straight forward approach is to let SSRS create the bindings to your dataset. I am not sure I am answering your question correctly as the only code portion supported directly via ssrs is through the vb code interface which can interface with .NET classes, however, that is not used for data access.

You can include data access in custom assemblies. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492756/return-a-response-to-indicate-no-data-via-the-reportexecution-renderreport-a) is an example of data binding using a ADO .NET Dataset. The example uses local report processing, however, the same can be applied to remote report. I know enough Crystal Reports to say that I doubt this is exactly what you are looking for but it is an alternative method for accessing data.

Comment: Thanks lrb. Yes, this is not exactly we're looking for. But I really appreciate your help.